# How to show welcome message only onetime when visit the home page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working with rails applications since some couple of months. Now I am supposed to add a feature to show the **welcome message** for the **first time** when user visits the site home page, and **not for second time** even the user reloads the same page.

How can I achieve this by using **jQuery** or **Javascript**?

Comment: What is wrong with my question? Can you explain please?

Comment: People are probably downvoting you because you can easily find the answer by searching, but I'll go you one better and suggest you use a cookie to see if someone visited the site before

Comment: When user visits a home page, show welcome message and set a cookie. If the cookie is already set, don't show message. You might be able to do it without any javascript at all (depending on presentation requirements).

Comment: use cookie to store the info that welcome message has been shown and perform a check on page load, if cookie is set don't show the message

Answer (score 5):

Simply set a cookie and check for it. If you use one of the usual jQuery cookie plug-ins, then put this script at the bottom of the page:

```
(function($) {

    if (!$.cookie("yourcookiename")) {
        $("selector for the message").show();
        $.cookie("yourcookiename", "x");
    }

})(jQuery);
```

That looks for the cookie and, if not found, shows content that you've defaulted to being hidden.

It's not *perfect*, because the user can clear cookies, but it's usually good enough.

Comment: Why dont we make this cookie expired instead of reset?

Comment: $.cookie("yourcookiename", "x"); instead of this, can't we make this cookie expired using Javascript? In server side code we set cookie expiration time to sometime back from the current date

Comment: @Murali: It's an *example*, and the precise way the cookie gets set will depend on which cookie plug-in the OP chooses to use.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you define first time, if you just mean registered user then you can record something on your server side.

If you mean anyone, you need firstly define who is this guy, writing a cookie to client browser might work but if they change a browser your message will show up again, record IP on server side might work but if some people sharing internet connection then only one person can really see it in that sub net.

Most of the case using cookie should be fine, or to with HTML5 local storage